# Organizing 8 separate tables in HTML on One Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to organize 8 tables in html on one page and I'm having a hard time placing them.  Any helpful tips? I attached the picture below for what I want the page to look like.  I'd appreciate any feedback from the community.  The tables hold different data.

[T8 Tables on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50J3g.png)

I tried different CSS classes for each table and I'm not successful. Maybe placing tables in html isn't possible?

Comment: IMHO, this is a job for CSS grid. In fact, you should have a good reason for you to _not_ be using CSS grid to make that layout. Also, keep accessibility in mind ie what happens when someone attempts to tab through those tables? And, what happens with smaller browser windows ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use grid, helpful here

you put your tables inside each div.

you can play with those values if you want to change row, col sizes

```css
      grid-template-rows: 30% 30% 25% 15%;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

you can also add some gap

(and remove background color, it's only to visualize the different div. Same with container 100vw 100vh widht and height if not needed)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30% 30% 25% 15%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(242, 161, 133, 0.5);
}

#div2 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(194, 36, 48, 0.5);
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
  background-color: rgba(130, 89, 39, 0.5);
}

#div4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 5 / 3;
  background-color: rgba(242, 237, 87, 0.5);
}

#div5 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(95, 135, 96, 0.5);
}

#div6 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(181, 119, 79, 0.5);
}

#div7 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(184, 129, 60, 0.5);
}

#div8 {
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 5 / 4;
  background-color: rgba(165, 223, 116, 0.5);
}

#container table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
        <td>td3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">div2</div>
  <div id="div3">div3</div>
  <div id="div4">div4</div>
  <div id="div5">div5</div>
  <div id="div6">div6</div>
  <div id="div7">div7</div>
  <div id="div8">div8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The issue I'm having now is that the column headers aren't aligning correctly to each table.  Each table has its own column headers.  I've been reading a lot but haven't found anything that can place the headers correctly.    I tried:  Header, nav{position: fixed;} nav{position: -webkit-sticky; position:  sticky; top: 0; ....  I think it's a lot less complicated than that though.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        display: flex;
      }
      .col {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        margin-top: 8px;
      }
      td, th {
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
      <h2> TABLE 1</h2>
        <table title="Table #1">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2> TABLE 7</h2>
        <table title="Table #7">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2> TABLE 8</h2>
        <table title="Table #8">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h2> TABLE 2</h2>
        <table title="Table #2">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h2> TABLE 3</h2>
        <table title="Table #3">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2> TABLE 4</h2>
        <table title="Table #4">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2> TABLE 5</h2>
        <table title="Table #5">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2> TABLE 6</h2>
        <table title="Table #6">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I populated each cell with a single space.  It should look like this:
[multiple tables in differnt colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK0Zk.png)